# variable declared inside method satisfy encapsulation or not

Tags: java

encapsulation is properties or method hiding using access modifier
i want to know is a variable declared inside function are encapsulated or not ??

Suppose there is a function

```
public String test-function()
   {
       int a ;    // are these two variables are encapsulated ???
       int b ;
   }
```

Comment: shouldn't you be googling a bit first???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two variables are method specific and would be on Stack rather than on the Heap. So encapsulation doesn't apply to method specific variables.

You should encapsulate fields specific to class (which constitutes to State of an object)